# Android ViewHolder with remote ImageView

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-viewholder

I Have implemented `ViewHolder` pattern im my `adapter`, where I have an `ImageView` populated with a remote image, the problem is when I scroll I always get a wrong image before having the correct one (after a fiew ms), I guess it is due to the fact that the current view IS a previously inflated view, but I don't see any possible solutions to this

```
if (rowView == null) {
       rowView  =   mInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout, parent, false);
       ViewHolder viewHolder                =   new ViewHolder();
       viewHolder.imageView     =   (ImageView)  rowView.findViewById(R.id.image);

       rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
}

ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();

viewHolder.imageView.setImageResource(0);
imageLoader.DisplayImage(URL, viewHolder.imageView);
```

Thank you

Comment: you are storing the ImageView in viewHolder.mEventCategoryImage, and setting the remote image to viewHolder.imageView. why?

Comment: I made a mistake copying the code, I fixed it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be on the right track with your code. The only issue is that `imageView.setImageResource(0)` doesn't seem to clear the image, at least on my Nexus 5 running kitkat.

Instead, perhaps try

`imageView.setImageDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.R.color.transparent));`

or maybe even setting the `ImageView's` visibility to `INVISIBLE`.

Comment: That actually would work, I'm using LazyList Library's ImageLoader and I set the default image to something, and now it seems to have worked. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

When you create the row in `getView`, call `setTag` on the `ImageView` using the URL string and remove whatever image is currently there. When the image finishes loading, before you set it on the `ImageView`, call `getTag` on it and check that the URL still matches.